# Linq ForEach - Returning cannot assign 'void' to an implicitly-typed local variable

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to use a linq query to save myself a few lines of code. 
I'm getting a compile error where I'm told:

> Returning cannot assign 'void' to an implicitly-typed local variable.

```
var GIANTLIST = new List<string>();

var taskIds = Complaint.Tasks.Select(s => s.Task_ID).ToList().ForEach( s =>
{
    GIANTLIST.Add("<Task_ID=" + s.ToString() + ">");
});
```

I'm trying to understand the linq query better. I understand that it's got a "void" return type? If this is the case how am I able to then add to the list?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Foreach it doesn't return any result; you can't assign it to a variable. Remove var taskIds:

```
var GIANTLIST = new List<string>();

Complaint.Tasks.Select(s => s.Task_ID).ToList().ForEach( s =>
{
    GIANTLIST.Add("<Task_ID=" + s.ToString() + ">");
});
```

Here you have microsoft documentation about it https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwabdf9z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

> I'm trying to understand the linq query better. I understand that it's
>   got a "void" return type? If this is the case how am I able to then
>   add to the list?

Think this ForEach as the usual functional ForEach ForEach(var a in MyList) which it doesn't return nothing is a void too. Inside ForEach you can modify directly the variables of your classes.

Answer (score 4):

that ForEach is not a part of Linq, it is a method of List class

keep it simple

```
var GIANTLIST = Complaint.Tasks.Select(s => "<Task_ID=" + s.Task_ID + ">").ToList();
```

if you need to add items to existing list, use AddRange instead of ForEach

```
GIANTLIST.AddRange(Complaint.Tasks.Select(s => "<Task_ID=" + s.Task_ID + ">"));
```

Answer (score 2):

The ForEach method returns void.  You are assigning `void` to the `taskIds`.  If you want to populate taskIds, do this:

```
            var GIANTLIST = new List<string>();
            var taskIds = new List<int>();
            Complaint.Tasks.Select(s => s.Task_ID).ToList().ForEach( s =>
            {
                taskIds.Add(s.TASK_ID);
                GIANTLIST.Add("<Task_ID=" + s.ToString() + ">");
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your trying to do two things at the same time. Selecting Task_ID into a list and adding each Task_ID to another list.

You can either do it in two steps

```
        var GIANTLIST = new List<string>();

        var taskIds = Complaint.Tasks.Select(s => s.Task_ID).ToList();

        taskIds.ForEach(s =>
        {
            GIANTLIST.Add("<Task_ID=" + s.ToString() + ">");
        });
```

or initialize both lists beforehand and add the values in the ForEach

```
        var GIANTLIST = new List<string>();
        var taskIds = new List<int>();

        Complaint.Tasks.Select(s => s.Task_ID).ForEach(s =>
        {
            taskIds.Add(s);
            GIANTLIST.Add("<Task_ID=" + s.ToString() + ">");
        });
```

The ForEach itself doesn't return anything, it just executes the specified action on every object of the list.